# C overflow or what is it?

Tags: c, overflow

I am reading two arrays of numbers along with their lengths and trying to find the sum of each arrays.

I am getting it correct for one but for other part, I don't get what happened? Can someone please look at it and help me out?

```
int m, n, snum, i, smun;
scanf("%d",&m);
int num[m];
for (i=0;i<m;i++) {
    scanf("%d",&num[i]);
    snum+=num[i];
}
scanf("%d",&n);
int mun[n];
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
    scanf("%d",&mun[i]);
    smun+=mun[i];
}
printf("%d %d ",smun,snum);
```

for this code, I can effectively get ***smun*** but ***snum*** is always wrong?
i.e.

```
for input:

 5
-2 -1 0 1 2
6
-3 -2 -1 1 2 3
my out put is: 0 -291502240
```

Comment: `int m,n,snum,i,smun;` - what number do you think is in snum at this point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize the sum variable to some value.

```
int m,n,snum,i,smun; 
snum=0;
smun=0;
scanf("%d",&m); 
int num[m]; 
for (i=0;i<m;i++){ 
     scanf("%d",&num[i]); 
     snum+=num[i]; 
} 
scanf("%d",&n); 
int mun[n]; 
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
scanf("%d",&mun[i]);
smun+=mun[i];
} 
printf("%d %d ",smun,snum);
```

When the variable is assigned an address it takes the data at that particular address, which we see as a junk or garbage value. The first output was right because you got lucky and the value in the address was alreay zero.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much undefined behavior because you did

```
int m,n,snum,i,smun;
```

And then accumulating to ***snum*** which in NOT initialized

```
snum+=num[i];
```

Doing something like

```
int m = 0;
int n = 0;
int snum = 0;
int i = 0;
int smun= 0;
```

Will provide the correct initialization and results

Comment: doesnt it set everything undefined to 0? or is that just java? but how come smun is calculated properly though?

Comment: Nop... In c or c++ there is no default value.

Comment: So those variables are holding garbage

Comment: but how come smun is calculated properly though?

Comment: I don't think it is a good thing to set the array length to `0`; since he needs elements in the array

Comment: you are rithgth, my fault with the arrays

Comment: @user7703770 this is just pure luck. You have a chance that it really does what you expect it to do. But you can not rely on that. This might work a thousand times and then not. Or always on your PC but not on the PC of your sister. It is undefined and quite often you can not even see it is undefined because by luck or sometimes a caring compiler undefined behavior works as you expect it.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize the snum and smun, it should be `snum = 0; smun = 0;`first then manipulate the sum.

Comment: int num[m] and int num[n], isnt that specifying the length of arrays?

Comment: @user7703770 yes sorry, missed that part, my bad